# What version on Ubuntu should I run my Rails app on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

My host gives me a few choices when it comes to distros. I know I want to run Ubuntu, but What version will give me the best compatibility with a typical rails app and the usual libraries I'd be using with Rails.

I have these available to me:

- Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy)
- Ubuntu 8.10 (intrepid)
- Ubuntu 9.04 (jaunty)
- Ubuntu 9.10 (karmic)

I'm tempted to just go with 9.10 just because its the newest... is that a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because rails/ruby is a fairly rapidly moving platform, I'd recommend going with the latest (9.10).

If the LTS (long term support) aspect is important to you, the next one is out in April (10.04)

Comment: Long term support - essentially a more conservative release schedule and longer supported lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine any reason to not to do so.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are still going to need to install a number of libraries regardless of your choice, so I would go with the newest version you have available.

Comment: yah that's true, I was mostly wondering if anyone knew of any **major** gotchas with any of the versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just go with 9.10.  That will give you the longest support period.